# Largest prefix list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I need to define a function `largestPrefix` that goes through a list of strings
and returns the longest prefix of two adjacent strings of the list in a tuple. The first element of the tuple is the length of the prefix .

a.e.: `largestPrefix ["a","abca","bca","bcadabca","ca","cdabca"] => (3,"bca")`

I have already built a function for two Stings, but have no idea how to use that on a list of lists. To ensure the adjacency I thought about using this:

```
 prefix:: String -> String -> String
 prefix (x:xs) (y:ys)   | x:xs == "" = ""
                        | y:ys == "" = ""
                        | x == y = x:prefix xs ys
                        | otherwise = ""
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I cleaned up your function a bit and added the following idea:

if you write a function that applies an operator to every two consecutive pairs of a list (`pairwise`) then you should be able to finish your work:

```
pairwise :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
pairwise f (x:xs@(y:_)) = f x y : pairwise f xs
pairwise _ _            = []

prefix:: String -> String -> String
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | x == y = x:prefix xs ys
  | otherwise = ""
prefix _ _ = ""
```

here is an example:

```
λ> pairwise prefix ["a","abca","bca","bcadabca","ca","cdabca"]
["a","","bca","","c"]
```

---

so maybe someone was unhappy because I did not resolve everything so here you go:

```
largestPrefix :: [String] -> (Int, String)
largestPrefix xs = maximumBy (compare `on` length . snd) $ zip [1..] (pairwise prefix xs)
```

where you have to import this to work:

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Function (on)
```

#### example

```
λ> largestPrefix ["a","abca","bca","bcadabca","ca","cdabca"]
(3,"bca")
```

Comment: I did not have downvoted you! 
Still try to understand your approach.

Comment: the approach is just to make a new list out of `[a,b,c,d...]` using an operator `f` by doing ``[f a b, f b c, f c d, ...]`` - so it's basically what you started

Comment: yes it is ;) ... also random downvote ... yay sunday on SO